# Is there a Storybook equivalent for .net Maui?

Tags: .net, maui, storybook

I've used React/Next JS in the past and an easy way to showcase UI components was Storybook JS. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent for .net Maui. I am using Maui for a client project at work so it will be good to be able to showcase individual components even if the parent page/control is not fully built yet.
I am aware of live-preview inside of Visual Studio which is helpful for developers but I'd like to know of a way I can showcase the UI components to the client.
Googled for a possible .net maui equivalent to storybook but found none.

Comment: Short answer: no, there is not